# Java Collectors groupBy with special behavior for certain key

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have a collection of objects:

```
List<PdfTitleCustomizationDto> dtoList = Arrays.asList(
            new PdfTitleCustomizationDto("Title 1", 1, "RRF", Set.of(new Role("ADMIN"))),
            new PdfTitleCustomizationDto("Title 2", 2, "Other", Set.of(new Role("USER"))),
            new PdfTitleCustomizationDto("Title 3", 3, "RRF", Set.of(new Role("ADMIN"))),
            new PdfTitleCustomizationDto("Title 4", 4, "Other", Set.of(new Role("ADMIN")))
    );
```

I need to group it by channel, which is "RRF" or "Other. However, if channel is "RRF", I have to get only one title with min order.
So the expected result should be:

```
{RRF=[Title 1], Other=[Title 4, Title 2]}
```

Do you have any ideas how to do it in one stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `groupBy`, and in the downstream, use `teeing` to split the stream into 2 - one does `minBy`, the other does `toList`. In the merger argument, you would check the title and decide whether to use the list, or the minimum element.

```
var y = list.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
                PdfTitleCustomizationDto::getChannel,
                Collectors.teeing(
                        Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparing(PdfTitleCustomizationDto::getTitle)),
                        Collectors.toList(),
                        (min, list) -> min
                                .filter(x -> "RRF".equals(x.getTitle()))
                                .map(List::of)
                                .orElse(list)
                )
        )
);
```

This does mean that everything, including those without the "RRF" title, will be `minBy`'ed, which is some extra processing that you wouldn't need to do otherwise.

If that is a problem, I recommend just `groupBy`, and remove the non-min elements from the resulting map, or just don't use streams at all.

Comment: Incompatible parameter types in lambda expression: expected List<Object> but found List<PdfTitleCustomizationDto here (min, list)

Comment: @yaroslav96 [I cannot reproduce that](https://ideone.com/Ijvu5m)

Comment: Really nice use of teeing. I can only think of collectingAndThen.

Comment: @samabcde considering that this approach will collect all lists anyway, a solution using `collectingAndThen` is not worse.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use Collector to get what you need

Have a look at the following code.

```
Map<String,List<PdfTitleCustomizationDto>> result = dtoList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        PdfTitleCustomizationDto::getChannel,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparingInt(PdfTitleCustomizationDto::getOrder)),
            optionalDto - > optionalDto.map(Collections::singletonList).orElse(Collections.emptyList())
        )
    ));
```

Comment: well, the result is not appropriate, we get only first title for each channel